# Heavily polymorphed table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `events`. Each event can be 'initiated' and/or 'received' by a `User`, `Visitor` or a `Team` and I want to model these associations.

I am thinking something like

```
Event
type
user_actor_id
user_subject_id
visitor_actor_id
visitor_subject_id
team_actor_id
team_subject_id
```

Where the actor/subject refers to who initiated/received the event

Is this the correct approach? Seems like I store a lot of redundant data and I'd have to do a lot of conditional joins as it would like to query the table and get a result like

```
actor_id:
actor_type (either user, visitor or team)
```

UPDATE:

Then i'd do a select query like this

```
    select
  coalesce(ua.id, va.id, ta.id) as actor_id,
  (CASE WHEN ua.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'user' WHEN va.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'visitor' ELSE 'team' END) as author_type,
  (CASE WHEN ua.id IS NOT NULL THEN ua.display_name WHEN va.id IS NOT NULL THEN va.name ELSE ta.name END) as author_name,
  (CASE WHEN ua.id IS NOT NULL THEN ua.avatar WHEN va.id IS NOT NULL THEN va.avatar ELSE ta.icon END) as author_name
from events e
  left join users ua on ua.id = e.user_actor_id
  left join users us on us.id = e.user_sibject_id
  left join visitors va on va.id = e.visitor_actor_id
  left join visitors vs on vs.id = e.visitor_sibject_id
  left join teams ta on ta.id = e.team_actor_id
left join teams ts on ts.id = e.team_sibject_id
```

Comment: Is it possible that e.g user_actor_id and user_subject_id are not null in the same time?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that is was a Visitor actor and a Team subject, so no user in the equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
create table tPeople ( -- contains as many rows as there are people
   int ID,
   nvarchar(max) Name
)

create table tRole ( -- contains three rows: Visitor, Team, User
   int ID,
   nvarchar(max) Name
)

create table tPeopleRole ( -- associates people with roles
   int People_ID, -- FK to tPeople.ID
   int Role_ID -- FK to tRole.ID
)

create table tEvent (
   int ID,
   int Type_ID,
   int InitiatedPeople_ID, -- FK to tPeople.ID
   int ReceivedPeople_ID -- FK to tPeople.ID
)
```

Then you can query `tEvent` and join on `tPeople` / `tPeopleRole` to get the initiator and receiver's names and/or roles.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach, but unfortunately it will be very difficult to make this change in my current schema

Comment: True, but then it should've been designed right in the first place.

Comment: Yes I agree, but changing requirements can sometimes be difficult to anticipate

Comment: @Tarlen What constraints are you stuck with?

Comment: Problem is I currently have visitors, users and teams in separate tables, and that some of my application-layer assumes this

Comment: You could maybe create vPeople, vRole, and vPeopleRole views from those three separate tables, although you can't FK to a view, so you'd lose referential integrity. Is it possible to refactor your application code so it expects a different schema?

Comment: It's possible, but if the approach i suggest in the updated post could be performant, i'd prefer to go with that